# Diagrama de Clases - Métodos

Tags: base-de-datos, uml, diseño-de-clases

**Hola!!**

Alguien puede ayudar por favor!!

Soy casi nueva en esto de Diagramas UML y estoy en creación del *Modelo de Clases* del proyecto y tengo una duda referente a los métodos de una clase.

*La pregunta es:*
¿Un método cuando debe ser **privado** y/o cuando debe ser **protegido**?

***Gracias!!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un método privado solo puede ser accedido desde la clase donde fue declarado.

Un método protegido puede ser accedido desde la clase donde fue declarado y desde las clases derivadas.

Por ejemplo:

Si tenes una clase Auto y un método ArrancarAuto(), el método es específicamente de tu clase, por lo tanto sería un método privado ya que no necesitas que lo vean desde ningún otro lado porque no lo usarían.

Si vos tenes la clase Vehículo con clases derivadas como Auto,Camion,etc.. y un método Arrancar(), este método debería ser protected, ya que necesitarías llamar el método Arrancar() de la clase padre y si fuera private no podrías o deberías volver a escribir el método, y el concepto de herencia no se estaría usando.

Un saludo!

Comment: Rompe alguna regla preguntar qué significa eso? Gracias...

Comment: Vos estas creando una clase, si el método que queres crear en esa clase no va a ser accedido desde ningún otro lado mas que en tu clase, tendría que ser un método privado. Edite mi respuesta con un ejemplo para que se pueda entender un poco mas.